# Azure: How to reload the Environment Variables without rebooting the App Service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, asp.net-core-2.1, azure-app-service-envrmnt

**What I’m trying to achieve**:
In an ASP.NET Core Web App, I want to listen for the configuration change event, and reload the new configuration value at run time. I'm changing the configuration setting by using the following CLI operation:

**For Example**:

```sh
az webapp config appsettings set --name $WebAppName --slot $SlotName --resource-group $ResourceGroupName --settings A_Setting_To_Monitor=$NewSettingValue
```

How can I detect this change event and load the new configuration value without resetting the App Service?

I'm using C# and .NET Core 2.1.

[image: The Application Settings of Azure Web App Service]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [Azure App Configuration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-app-configuration/overview).

> Azure App Configuration provides a service to centrally manage application settings. Modern programs, especially programs running in a cloud, generally have many components that are distributed in nature. Spreading configuration settings across these components can lead to hard-to-troubleshoot errors during an application deployment. Use App Configuration to store all the settings for your application and secure their accesses in one place.
>
> App Configuration makes it easier to implement the following scenarios:
>
> - Centralized management and distribution of hierarchical configuration data for different environments and geographies
> - **Dynamic configuration changes without the need to redeploy or restart an application**
> - Feature management

Comment: When changing environment variable values in a container, and using GetEnvironmentVariables.Get(name), they refresh. Is there a feature parity way to do this with isolated azure functions?